# Java OOP instance of class

Tags: java, oop

I have following classes structure extention:
`Entity` > `Creature` > (abstract)`Player` > `Mage`. 
In `Mage` class I implement interface `iCastable` with method `castSpell()`. In main method I create `new Mage(...)`.

Problem is that when I send it as a prop of Player class `someMethod(Player player)`, I cannot use methods implemented from interface `iCastable`. I can only use methods from `Creature` class via `player.getCreaure.whaterver()` because `Player` extend it. How can I solve that issue?

I do not want to send it as a prop of `Mage` class, because I want to use all my other classes like `Warrior` for example. I also want to avoid `player instanceof Mage`, because if I had 1000 classes I must do 1000 check for every method. Do you have any ideas how to solve that?

**EDIT** added code

```
public class Creature extends Entity {...}

public abstract class Player extends Creature {
    public Player(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
    public abstract void attack();
}
public class Mage extends Player implements iCastable {
    ...
    @Override
    public void castSpecial() {...}
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   Mage mage = new Mage("Mage");
   Duel duel = new Duel(mage, monsters);
}
public class Duel {
    private Player player;
    ...
    public Duel(Player player, ArrayList<Monster> monsters) {
        this.player = player;
        ...
    }
    private void castSpecial() {
        // error here
        player.castSpecial();
    }
}
```

I am trying to do something like player.getInstanceClass(mage, warrior or whatever).cashSpecial()

Comment: Why do you extend the interface `iCastable` rather than implementing it

Comment: Typing mistake sorry

Comment: It would help if we could see code, us programmer are better at reading code than English :)

Comment: on what class/interface is the `someMethod(Player player)` defined ?

Comment: I suspect we need to understand more about the intended structure and functionality here.  Based on the description alone... If the method expects a `Player` then the method's internal functionality *shouldn't care* what kind of `Player`.  If the method's internal functionality is specific to a `Mage` then it *should expect* a `Mage`.  What exactly does `someMethod()` do?  If you were to give it a meaningful and descriptive name, what would it be?

Comment: added some code

Comment: If the method on `Duel` is called `castSpecial` then it sounds like that method, indeed that class, is really designed for a `Mage` and not just a `Player`.  Conceptually, what does `Duel` do?

Comment: I am trying to do something like player.getInstanceClass(mage, warrior or whatever) .cashSpecial()

Comment: So a `Warrior` should also be able to `castSpecial()`?  It's starting to sound like the `Duel` class should take an `iCastable`, not a `Player`.

Comment: Duel just fires phases: attack, defence, cast spell...

Comment: @TeodorKolev: "phases" could be a clue here.  Now it's starting to sound like the "actions" of various players follow a predictable pattern.  An abstract class or interface could define that pattern, with more generic names.  `attackPhaseAction()`, `defensePhaseAction()`, etc.  The `Duel` could define the rules of how to cycle through those actions/phases.  What each implementing class does on each of those actions/phases is its own internal implementation, which may internally call `Mage`-specific or `Warrior`-specific methods.

Comment: @David please focus on question I ask, not on Duel class

Comment: @TeodorKolev: The error is happening in the `Duel` class.  The "question" is a *very* general: *"Do you have any ideas how to solve that?"*  Please clarify the question if what you're apparently *not* looking for is how to structure the classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method can be written like this:

```
private void castSpecial() {
    if (player instanceof iCastable) {
        ((iCastable) player).castSpecial();
    }
}
```

The `instanceof` performs a runtime check to see if the `Player` instance has the correct subclass.  If the check succeeds then the type cast will also succeed.  (If you do the type cast without a "guard", then it will throw an ClassCastException if the player doesn't have the required type.)

Obviously, if the `player` does not have spell casting ability, the method does nothing.

---

Note: the interface name `iCastable` is wrong from two perspectives.

1. A class or interface name should **never** start with a lowercase letter.
2. The name is wrong.  `ICastable` implies that you would "cast" a `Mage`.  In fact, the `Mage` is the subject, that casts the spell, not the spell that is cast.  A better name might be `ISpellCaster`.

Comment: This is the answer I am looking for

Comment: Bear in mind that if you're doing a lot of instanceof checks and downcasts it can be a code smell. It seems like this use-case might be better solved using composition rather than inheritance. For example each creature could contain an array of IAbility and casting a spell could be a type of ability, used by calling IAbility.activate() for example, without any need to downcast.